# Downloading a video in an iPhone app, is there any file size limit?

Tags: iphone, video, download

I am trying to work out if I can have my app download a couple videos that may change from time to time. It all seems possible in my research, but my one concern is if the size of the video file would be an issue? They are not going to be extremely large, but they are videos and from what I see they may have to go through the memory before saving to the storage.

Any pointers, advice, or thoughts would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You can save directly to file using the awesome and highly recommended [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/)

If you are serious about this, ensure you tell the user first. Users who do not have unlimited data will hate you if you download a large movie without telling them.